# I have a windows pc, can I develop with LAMP?

Tags: hosting, wamp, lamp, web-hosting, cloud-hosting

I have a pc running windows but I want to use a linux server.  Is there a way for me to develop my website on my computer before I rent space on a server?  Also its probably important to note that I have no linux experience.  Should I just stick with wamp?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you specifically **and purposely** use .NET features in your PHP Application, then an application developed in [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) will work fine on a [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) Server as long as you have included all the same PHP plugins.

PHP is independent from Linux or Windows. 99.9% of the time you have to **knowingly** use features from the host OS.

Comment: Oh. Well thats great news, I guess I didn't really think of it that way.  Thanks!

Comment: @nschamb1 You should choose best answers then. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try ubuntu in a virtualbox, there are lots of well written guides that'll get you up and running.

Answer (score 0):

For best performance, use coLinux. Install a linux distro like ubuntu (easier for beginners) and you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I have developed and maintained a website like this before. My development environment was WAMP and the server was a LAMP shared server. Shouldn't be a problem till your site is using fairly basic libraries and they are available both for windows/linux.

However as others mentioned, its wiser to have the development environment as close possible to the production environment. You don't hit any surprises that way. And hey its not difficult and involves no cost:

- You can use dual boot to have linux as other operating system.
- Depending on your machine, you can just install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and install a Linux VM.